React: console.log in button click handler not showing updated state
I am building a React application where I have a button that should log the current state to the console. However, the console.log inside the button's onClick handler always logs the initial state, not the updated one. Here’s my code:
export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');

  const addUser = () => {
    const obj = {
      name: 'old user name',
      updateName: (
        <button onClick={() => setName('new user name')}>update name</button>
      ),
      showName: <button onClick={() => console.log(name)}>show name</button>,
    };
    setUsers([obj, ...users]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addUser}> add user</button>
      {users &&
        users.map((user) => (
          <div>
            {user.name}
            {user.updateName}
            {user.showName}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

When I click the "Update Name" button, it updates the name state to "new user name" as expected. However, when I click the "Show Name" button, it logs the initial state of name (an empty string) instead of the updated state ("new user name").
I moved the console.log call to a separate function outside the component, but it still logs the initial state.
How can I make the console.log inside the button's onClick handler reflect the updated state?
Any help would be appreciated!

This:
<button onClick={() => console.log(name)}>show name</button>

is capturing that state value and never being updated when that state value changes.
Don't store components/functions/etc. in state.  Store data in state.  The rendering of the component can build the structure it needs from that data.
In this case, that should mean just removing those buttons from state and rendering them when they're needed.  For example:
export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');

  const addUser = () => {
    const obj = {
      name: 'old user name',
    };
    setUsers([obj, ...users]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addUser}> add user</button>
      {users &&
        users.map((user) => (
          <div>
            {user.name}
            <button onClick={() => setName('new user name')}>update name</button>
            <button onClick={() => console.log(name)}>show name</button>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}


It's worth noting that to achieve the functionality you may be trying to build, you may have more coding to do.  (For example, you may be intending to connect in some way the name state with the users state at some point, and just haven't done that yet.)
What you have here appears to be very unfinished and mostly just testing functionality as a proof of concept.  This answer makes no attempt to speculate on intended functionality, just attempting to correct the specific issue at hand.
